# ValueError: Field 'maca' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django, web

I have a model like this

```
class MacaModel(models.Model):
    maca = models.PositiveIntegerField(
       db_column='Maca', blank=True, null=True
    )
```

I have form like this

```
class MacaForm(models.ModelForm):
    maca = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Maca'}))
```

I'm trying to send null value from input, but got this error

```
ValueError: Field 'maca' expected a number but got ''.
```

How can I handle if I don't send a value accept is as a None value or something like that?

Comment: you can use the `forms.NumberInput` field in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that the field should work with `None` in case it has not been filled in. You can do that by setting the [**`empty_value=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.empty_value):

```
class MacaForm(models.ModelForm):
    maca = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        empty_value=None,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Maca'})
    )
```

Comment: how is empty_value in case of choicefield?

Comment: @maca: it is not the `ChoiceField`, the link refers to the `empty_value` of the `CharField`. If you scroll up a bit, you see that it belongs to the `CharField` section.

Comment: Yes you're right! But this is just one case of my model. Empty Fields is not accepted for all. If you can help me for choice field now to set value for empty case I would be very thankful. Btw + 1

Comment: @maca: you should work with a `TypedChoiceField`. In that case you can specify the `empty_value`.